# Extracting URL in Matlab regexp

Tags: regex, matlab

I'm trying to get familiar with regexp. Nonetheless I am still encountering some issues. I want to extract just the URLs from:

```
regularexpression = '';       
script = ['I <I>used</I> <B>to</B> visit <THE> website <A HREF=www.lichess.org>twice a day</A>. ' ...
'Visit <I>the website</I> <A HREF=www.bing.com>or alternatively</A> just <A HREF=www.google.com> for more information</A>.']
x = regexp(script,regularexpression,'match')
```

This should provide a 1X3 cell array {'www.lichess.org'} {'www.bing.com'} {'www.google.com'}

Comment: Assuming all url's starts with **www**, this can do the trick : **www.[^>]***

Comment: Great, thank you. and what if I were to match just the italic words, that is those captured in <I>word<I>.  This should give {'used'} {'the website'}.

Comment: **(?<=\<I\>)[^<]*** ,there's another way, but if works, i can add them as an answer explaining if you want.

Comment: If you only need to extract href from anchor tags then you can use this, (?i)<a.*href=(.*?)>.*?<\/a> Grab everything in group1

Comment: (?i)<i>(.*?)<\/i> for italics

Comment: To catch URL's that do not necessarily start with `www` you can use `'(?<=A HREF=)[^>]*(?=>)'`

Comment: thank you that would be great!

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi i got the idea, but how to avoid the anchors? According to your code gives: {'<I>very</I>'}    {'<I>for example</I>'} and not {'very'}    {'for example'}

Comment: For <I> enclosed elements : `>> tokens = regexp(script,'<I>([^<]+)','tokens'); >> tokens{:}`

Comment: @rjkvc: There is a group present in the regex. (.*) You need to capture group 1. If you want, I can add an answer with details and demo.

Answer (score 0):

```
regularexpression = 'www\.[^>]*'; 
script = ['I <I>used</I> <B>to</B> visit <THE> website <A HREF=www.lichess.org>twice a day</A>. ' ...
'Visit <I>the website</I> <A HREF=www.bing.com>or alternatively</A> just <A HREF=www.google.com> for more information</A>.']
x = regexp(script,regularexpression,'match')
```

Output:

```
  1×3 cell array

    {'www.lichess.org'}    {'www.bing.com'}    {'www.google.com'}
```